# How to change the sequence of requests in scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrap multiple page into one item:

```
A
|-- a
|-- b
|-- c
B
|-- a
...
```

By scraping page A and its subpages (a, b, c) I'll get 1 item. My code is huge but here is the shrinked version:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    def parse(self, response):
        for li in response.xpath('//li'):
            item = MyItem()
            ...
            meta = {
                'item': item,
                'href': href,
            }
            url = response.urljoin(href + '?a')
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_a, meta=meta)

    def parse_a(self, response):
        ...

        url = response.urljoin(href + '?b')
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_b, meta=meta)


    def parse_b(self, response):
        ...

        url = response.urljoin(href + '?c')
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_c, meta=meta)


    def parse_c(self, response):
        ...
        yield item
```

Script works fine but here is the problem: Crawler scrabs pages in following order: `A, B, C, Aa, Ba, Ca, Ab, Bb, ...` since there are too many pages to scrab nothing is saved until all of the pages are scrabed. And when I change `yield` to `return` on parse method it scrabs the way I want `A, Aa, Ab, Ac` but it doesn't scrab B, C, ...

Comment: When you use `return` it works the way you want only for the first page, because only the first `Request` for page `A` is returned in `parse` method.

Comment: Also if you have a lot of pages, then it can happen that page `Ac` will be scraped before some `Xb` page, because requests are made asynchronously and processing of page `Ac` does not wait for page `Xb`, the order only depends on how long does it take to get the `Response` object back from the server for `Request` object `Ac` and if that response is before `Xb`, then that item will be sent to Item pipeline before `Xc`.

Comment: What output medium are you using, cvs, xml, database, etc.?

Comment: @JernejJerin Thanks, I'm checking your responses.

Comment: @Steve I am using mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enforce this type of order, the only way that I can think of now is to specify the order in [Item Pipeline](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) so that you will be returning `Ac Bc Cc ...`.